# How to link my product page details in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, hyperlink

I try to link my product detail page but this link  doesn't work

```
href="{{ url('product/detail/'.$product->id)}}"
```

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? White page? Wrong product detail? Why `vue.js`? What does `$product->id` contain? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this link doesn't work for me

Comment: are you using vuejs for frontend view or blade template?

Comment: That's ... not very helpful either. "_doesn't work for me_" means what? You can't click it? Is the wrong detail page shown?

Comment: yes im using vue.js

Comment: `{{ url('product/detail/'.$product->id)}}` is `blade` syntax, doesn't work in Vue

Comment: you have to use vue-router or create link string and attach it with :href in vuejs

Comment: In vuejs do this `:href="'/product/detail/'+product.id"`. But you must define `product` as data property in your vue component.

Comment: @MAY thank you very much it's working now the problem is using blad syntax

Comment: no problem, but please ask the question properly next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define route in web file as such:

```
Route::get('/product/detail/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'show'])->name('product.details');
```

In vuejs do this

```
:href="'/product/detail/'+product.id".
```

But you must define `product` as data property in your vue component.

In blade template use this format

```
href="{{ route('product.details', $product->id) }}"
```